# Android Apps to asynchronously read some kind of buffer

Tags: android, buffer, shared-memory

I am currently assigned the task to research and implement two Apps that do the following:

- App A writes some content to a buffer/register of some sort
- App A terminates
- App B starts and reads the Buffer

The Apps are not supposed to run at the same time.

First of all I don't know which possibilities I have. 
I came up with the following:

1. Write to a File
2. Write to some shared memory range

Are those two options possible and do i have to grant App B the right to access the file or memory range?

Furthermore i am supposed to check network sockets for usage as "buffer".
I know that would go against everything that is supposed to be done but this is expected!
I was trying to use a DatagramSocket because i can open up that kind of socket, send packets over it, close the socket and terminate the App.
I thought there would be some system buffer holding the packets until someone calls receive on a DatagramSocket with the same port. 
Would that even be possible or will the system throw all packets away when nobody is receiving them immediately?

Answer (score 0):

There is a class in the android API that was created specifically to allow you sharing data between different applications - the `ContentProvider`.

You should create a `ContentProvider` that will be in charge of the data (I recommend using the SQLite database to store the data), and both apps can use that same `ContentProvider` to access and/or modify the data.

It does not matter in which of the apps the `ContentProvider` resides, but probably best it is in App A since it is the one creating and modifying the data.

See this great guide on how to create a `ContentProvider`:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Except that, with a `ContentProvider`, both apps are running at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I will consider a ContentProvider for the task but i should think of something around the normal way of sharing Data between Apps. I've got some detection tool which logs communication of two apps and i should prove that it will detect those communications aswell or if not I should change it that it does.